# 2-dimensional Cohen-Macaulay domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, cohen-macaulay

> I am searching for a $2$-dimensional Cohen-Macaulay (normal or not) domain.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $R[x]$ where $R$ is a discrete valuation ring, or more generally a Dedekind domain?

For me, a Dedekind domain is a Noetherian normal domain of dimension $1$ and a DVR is a regular local ring of dimension $1$. So in either case the ring $R[x]$ is $2$-dimensional.

Comment: (I guess the assumption that $R$ is not a field is baked in your definitions somewhere, but it might not hurt to emphasize it.) @karparvar Remember this strategy! Being C-M and being a domain is invariant under forming polynomial rings: but dimension is not invariant when you form the polynomial ring!

Comment: Dear @karparvar, if $A$ is a Noetherian ring of dimension $d$ then $A[x]$ has dimension $d+1$. So no, $\mathbf{Z}[x]$ is not a Dedekind domain.